# UINavigationBar disappears in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to make my iOS app design looking like iOS 11 standard apps.I added UISearchController in UINavigationBar.Search is working good, but when user selects cell and goes to destinationViewController the UINavigationController disappears.Here is the screenshots : [how navigation looks like in root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hw1o.jpg) and
[disappeared navigation in destinationVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Gc0.jpg)

What can cause this problem?

NOTE:If I don't use search and just select cell the destinationVC will be normal with Navigation, BackButton and Tittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and added:

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```